# Trigger Kafka Consumer on receiving data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a producer application which sends data to a Kafka topic, but only once in a while, as and when it receives from a source. I also have a consumer application (Spark) which keeps running all the time and receives data from Kafka when producer sends to it.

Since the consumer keeps running all the time, there is wastage of resources at times. Moreover, because my producer sends data only once in a while, is there any way to trigger the consumer application only when a kafka topic gets any data?

Comment: In your case you can check if data available in topic then process else stop the consumer application for X time, and then repeat.

Comment: You can also configure `max.poll.interval.ms` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you shouldn't be using Spark and would rather run some Serverless solution that can be triggered to run code on Kafka events.

Otherwise, run Cron to look at consumer lag. Define a threshold to submit your code at, then batch read from Kafka only then